# Separating every forth string character in Java

Tags: java, string, space

My problem looks like that:
I want to disconnect a string with spaces at every forth index going forward.

The desired effect would be like that:
Input:
"DE123589823431"

Output:
"DE12 3589 8234 31"

I found a good resource already on here which gave me the following:

```
String str = "FR13446434523"
String[] split = str.split("(?<=\\G....)");

for (String index : split){
System.out.println(index);
}
```

Unfortunately this gives me the following output:

FR13

4464

3452

3

I thought the fatal error is a simple fix: Just remove the "ln" from "println".
That didn't seem to work for whatever reason, because my string suddenly doesn't have any spaces anymore.
The output was like that:
FR13446434523

I have no idea where the flaw in my logic is..
Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: System.out.print(split+" ");

Comment: Perhaps understand what System.out.print and System.out.println do? Your strings are all split correctly. But if you are using print, it is going to print the string and not add spaces to it. In your case, you would want to print the space after every word print. Something like this: `System.out.print(index + " ");` Note that this would also print a space after the last word. You would have to figure out how to do that

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I don't know why I didn't get that myself..

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "FR13446434523"
String[] split = str.split("(?<=\\G....)");
String dest = String.join(" ", split);
```

should work

Comment: Even shorter using RegEx: `System.out.println("DE123589823431".replaceAll("(.{4})", "$1 "));`